# UltiSnips : how to expand the content of a snippet with the content of a register

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

In UltiSnips, it is possible to use the ${VISUAL} inside of a snippet to directly paste some text inside a snippet. The behaviour works as follow :

- Select the text to paste in visual mode
- Press Tab(Or the snippet-expand-key)
- The text disappears
- Enter insert mode and type and expand a snippet
- The snippet expand with the ${VISUAL} replaced by the deleted text.

Is it possible somehow to put something in the "visual" register from another register(for instance the clipboard) so that the next visual snippet expand will paste it ?

Comment: I was just wondering this exact thing: how can I yank some text, type a snippet trigger, and then have the snippet expand using that yanked text somewhere within it? E.g., in latex, yank the argument of a `\label{crossref}` command, then type `ref<tab>` somewhere else to get `\ref{crossref}`.